# My project builds in my computer but not in local host jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I am new to Jenikns. Please help to resolve this.

Mine is a Maven project and it builds successfully in Eclipse. But when I am trying to build it through local host Jenkins (Source code from SVN), its throwing error -

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project IPR: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.IPR.runner.IPRRunner-e -> [Help 1]

where IPRRunner is part of my framework and the framework library is in my company central repo.

Comment: Did you configure maven settings on Jenkins agent to use your Company Central Repo ? What is the reported error ?

Comment: No. I did not know that we should configure Maven settings in Jenkin. Please see the error that I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: The error I am getting is that it is unable to find the class with main method.                                                                                                           In Jenkins configure -> Invoke Top level Maven Targets -> Goal ->compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.IPR.runner.IPRRunner"                                      .But it is throwing error class not found - com.IPR.runner.IPRRunner